# Emacs でタブをそのままタブとして入力したい

Tags: emacs

FreeBSD で Emacs 25.2.1 を使っているのですが、fundamental-mode において
タブをそのままタブとして入力させたいのですが、設定方法を教えてください。

今は、スペースになったり、直前行のインデントを継続しようとしたりしており、
これを無効化したいです。

.emacs に (electric-indent-mode -1) を書きましたがうまくいっておりません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問の仕方が悪かったのですが、例えば  
　`a(TAB)(TAB)b`  
　`[カーソル]`  
の状態でTABを押すと  
　`a(TAB)(TAB)b`  
　`(TAB)[カーソル]`  
となってほしいのに、直前行を解釈して  
　`a(TAB)(TAB)b`  
　`(TAB)(TAB)[カーソル]`  
となってしまうのを抑止したい、TAB を押下した分だけそのまま TAB を埋め込んでほしいという意図でした。  

indent-tabs-mode では効果ありませんでしたが、defadvice にてうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 改行の仕方がうまくいかないままコメント編集期限5分間を過ぎてしまいましたが、`a(TAB)(TAB)b(改行)[カーソル]` と解釈いただければと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-q</kbd> (`M-x quoted-insert`) を利用すれば、その次のキー入力をそのままバッファに挿入することができます。タブ入力なら <kbd>C-q <TAB></kbd> ですね。

TAB キーをタブ入力として扱いたい場合は `.emacs` (または `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) に以下の設定を追加してください。ただし、すべてのメジャーモードで有効になるため意図する挙動ではないかもしれません。

```
;; タブインデントを有効にする
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)

;; 仮にテキストモード限定で有効にしたいのならば、こういう書き方ができる
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```

※ fundamental-mode は他のメジャーモードとは扱いが異なるため、このモード限定で設定を書き換えるのは若干面倒です。コメントで需要があれば追記します。

Answer (score 2):

別解として `defadvice` を使う方法などを。

```elisp
(defadvice fundamental-mode (after insert-tab-char-as-is activate)
  (local-set-key (kbd "TAB") (lambda () (interactive) (insert ?\t))))
```